# padding the space above a css button

Tags: css, button, padding

I'm trying to add `padding` to the space above a button created with CSS. The button CSS already has `padding` in it around the text so if I try to add `padding-top` it just changes the size of the button rather than move it down closer to the element below it which is what I'm trying to do.

**This is the CSS:**

```
button {
  background:    #c00;
  background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#c00, #600);
  background:    linear-gradient(#c00, #600);
  border-radius: 999px;
  color:         #f6f4f4;
  padding:       10px 100px;
  font:          normal 700 24px/1 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  text-align:    center;
  text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
  margin-left: 80px;
}
```

Comment: try margin-top.

Answer (score 4):

Add one more styling property in your button.

```
button{

     margin-top:10px;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want top padding of this css then you have to use the following css instead of:

```
button {

        background:    #c00;
        background:    -webkit-linear-gradient(#c00, #600);
        background:    linear-gradient(#c00, #600);
        border-radius: 999px;
        color:         #f6f4f4;
        padding:       10px 100px 10px 100px;
        font:          normal 700 24px/1 "Open Sans", sans-serif;
        text-align:    center;
        text-shadow:   1px 1px 0 #000;
        margin-left: 80px;
    }
```

The css line: **padding: 10px 100px 10px 100px;** how much you want to use  change it first part like padding: 50px 100px 10px 100px;

But the question is that if you want top padding of upper position of the button not inside the button then you have to use

```
.anyClassName{
    margin-top: 10px;
}
```

use this class html tag which is contain the button.

Answer (score 0):

An even better solution I think would be to add margin bottom to the element above your button: http://csswizardry.com/2012/06/single-direction-margin-declarations/

Answer (score 0):

actually I just figured it out. I added a div tag around the button and added padding-top to the div.

Sorry for wasting your time. I am new to this coding :)

Comment: use `margin-top`, other users have said you. `padding` is for padding (inside) and `margin` for margin (outside)